# I cant use the free the fish easter egg in 14.04

Tags: easter-egg

I type in 'free the fish' and all i get is a message saying, 'still no easter eggs in ubuntu'. How do I access this easter egg?

Comment: IIRC, the easter egg is that there is no easter egg.

Answer (score 3):

The original easter egg was in the old GNOME 2 desktop environment. That's long gone, and now the only easter egg is that Unity still doesn't have easter eggs. GNOME Shell certainly doesn't have this easter egg.